# Why does GCC think that the template parameter is int whereas it's a completely different type?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

I have a problem with compiling the following program using GCC (I've tried numerous versions, all fail with the same error). It compiles fine in Clang:

```
#include <vector>

struct Tag1
{
    static void logAllocation(){}
    static void logDeallocation(){}
};
struct Tag2
{
    static void logAllocation(){}
    static void logDeallocation(){}
};

template<typename Tag, typename T>
struct MyAllocator
{
    using value_type = typename std::allocator<T>::value_type;

    T* allocate(std::size_t n)
    {
        Tag::logAllocation();
        return std::allocator<T>{}.allocate(n);
    }

    void deallocate(T* p, std::size_t n)
    {
        Tag::logDeallocation();
        std::allocator<T>{}.deallocate(p, n);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int, MyAllocator<Tag1, int>> vec;
}
```

The problem is that GCC thinks that `Tag==int` inside `MyAllocator` and I get an error that *'logDeallocation' is not a member of 'int'*. Is this a bug in GCC? When I flip template parameters (`template<typename T, typename Tag`) and declare my vector as `std::vector<int, MyAllocator<int, Tag1>> vec;` it compiles.

Comment: Works with clang.

Comment: @BaummitAugen - What version? [Clang 3.8 emits a similar error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dbdfcaa186efbfc4).

Comment: @StoryTeller clang5 https://wandbox.org/permlink/iZeRLPwtAHcHyPfc

Comment: The problem seems to be that `_Vector_Base::_Tp_alloc_type` resolves to `MyAllocator<int, int>`.  This is defined by  `typedef typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Alloc>::template  rebind<_Tp>::other _Tp_alloc_type;`  . I'm not an expert on allocators, but it could be that your allocator is missing something needed to make the `rebind` work as intended

Comment: @M.M - You should post it as an answer. According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits#Member_alias_templates), it seems to be due to the "otherwise" clause.

Comment: @StoryTeller I don't really know what I'm talking about here, would rather leave it to someone more familiar with allocators

Comment: I've added Tag1 and Tag2 implementation to my original question to avoid confusion. I'm using wandbox.org for compilation with following flags: `g++ prog.cc -Wall -Wextra -std=c++17`. It's the same on e.g. GCC 5.1.0, 6.1.0, 8.0.1

Comment: @rubix_addict, thanks I can repeat now. Interesting find! I'll be interested in the answer.

Comment: Adding `template< class U >
    struct rebind {
        using other = MyAllocator<Tag, U>;
    };` to `MyAllocator` seemed to make it work.

Comment: Just invert the order of `Tag` and `T` in the template argument list for `MyAllocator`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Yes, that works. Now I wonder why does it work on Clang without rebind.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is not a conforming allocator, and supplying it as one to a library component results in undefined behavior (thus, both implementations are conforming). You are missing `!=`, `==`, cross-type implicit conversion, and, as pertinent here, `rebind`.

`allocator_traits`'s default `rebind` implementation assumes that the value type is the first template parameter (and that any remaining template parameters can be reused unmodified). Since it's not the case for your allocator, you need to either supply your own `rebind` or invert the template parameter order.

---

`vector` is pretty special in that the implementation can, if it wants to, simply use the supplied allocator as-is without rebinding. That's why your example code compiles with libc++. libstdc++'s containers support an extension that allows you to do `vector<int, allocator<char>>`, so it always rebinds the allocator to the specified `value_type`.